# React, reason for avoiding mutating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know mutating state can work against `PureComponent` (or similar)
Is there other reason not to mutate state?

I wonder if the 3rd way is ok to do?

> ```
>   // The Right Way:
>   // copy the existing items and add a new one
>   addItemImmutably = () => {
>     this.setState({
>       items: [...this.state.items, this.makeItem()]
>     });
>   };
>
>   // The Wrong Way:
>   // mutate items and set it back
>   addItemMutably = () => {
>     this.state.items.push(this.makeItem());
>     this.setState({ items: this.state.items });
>   };
>  // is this ok? (mutate but set state with new copy)
>  addItem3rdWay = () => {
>    this.state.items.push(this.makeItem());
>    this.setState({items: [...this.state.items]});
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thou shalt not mutate state!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: You have fired an async method that sends a request with your current state data. In meantime you have executed a function that mutates the state. This will cause the async function to send the mutated state despite the fact it intended to send the state before mutation.

Answer (score 1):

You can think `state` as your database.

You don't directly mutate your database, you modify your database by **API**.

`setState` is the `API`.

Of course, you can directly mutate your **database**, but other components will have a hard time retrieving those data, because those are inconsistent right now, because somebody doesn't use the **API** that framework provides for you.

If you really like the way mutating state, you can use `Vue`, Vue is designed like that.